# Prove that if the image of a holomorphic function $g$ is contained in the union of n distinct lines, then $g$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $L_1,.., L_n \subset \mathbb R^2$ (or $\mathbb C$) be n distinct lines. Prove that if $g: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a holomorphic function and $g(\mathbb C) \subset L_1 \cup L_2 \cup ... \cup L_n$, then $g$ is constant.

I would appreciate any hint for this exercise since I don't know what to do. Is there a more general theorem from which I could conclude this? Maybe something related to holomorphic functions where the image is the union of connected sets.

Another thing I thought of is trying to prove it by the absurd but I got stuck, I mean, suppose $g$ is not constant, then it takes at least two different values $w_1$ and $w_2$, from here how could I arrive to an absurd?

Comment: Try proving that if $g$ is entire and its image doesn't meet a disk, it must be constant. I gave a hint in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A holomorphic function has the open mapping property whereever the derivative is nonzero, so your function always has the derivative vanish (since a union of lines contains no open set), so it is a constant.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know that theorem.

Answer (score 0):

As Igor mentioned previously, the open mapping property suffices to solve this problem. However, I got this solution that doesn't rely on such theorem and I think can be useful for others.

First, note that either $u$ or $v$ must take no more than $n$ values (if not, we'd have a grid of $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ values in the image of $g$, which can't be covered by $n$ lines).

Since $g$ is holomorphic, both $u$ and $v$ must be differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$, hence continuous. Therefore, if the image of any of them is a set of finite values, it results constant.

To conclude, recall that if $g=u+iv$ is holomorphic, and either $u$ or $v$ is constant, $g$ must be constant as well.

Comment: Hi, I don't seem to understand why do $u$ and $v$ take no more than $n$ values. Couldn't all  the values they take be collinear? I mean if you take $n=1$ why does it follow that both $u$ and $v$ are constant? If $f$ is holomorphic then it's true but you aren't using it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Let $a \notin L_1 \cup L_2 \cup .. \cup L_n$. Show that 
$$h(z)=\frac{1}{g(z)-a}$$
is entire and bounded.

**Note** Same way you can prove the more general result: if $g$ is entire you can find some $a \in \mathbb C$ and $r>0$ such that $g(\mathbb C) \cap D_r(a)=\emptyset$ then $g$ is constant.